# Laravel database insert data with multiple checkbox

Tags: php, laravel

I have segments and categories.I want to put categories in segment when cliked checkbox.So i tried to this.But it doesn't working.Where i did mistake

```
$data = array();
$data['name'] = $request->name;
$data['is_active'] = $request->is_active;
$validateData = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|unique:segments',
    'category_id' => 'required',
]);
$segment=Segment::create($data);
if (isset($request->category_id) && isset($request->is_main_category)) {
    $category_ids[] = $request->input('category_id');
    $segment_category_data=[];
    foreach ($category_ids as $key=>$value) {
            $segment_category_data['category_id'] = $request->input("category_id.$value");
           $segment_category_data['segment_id'] = $segment->id;
           $segment_category_data['is_main_category'] = $request->input("is_main_category.$value");
    }
$segment_categories=DB::table('segment_categories')->create($segment_category_data);
```

And then i do it in blade

```
@foreach($category as $row)
    <tr>
        <td> {{$i++}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->category_name}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-check form-check-success col-md-4">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="hidden" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="category_id[{{$row->id}}]" value=0>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="category_id[{{$row->id}}]" type="checkbox" value={{$row->id}}>  Add to Segment <i class="input-helper"></i>
                    </label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-check form-check-success-4">
                     <label class="form-check-label">
                         <input type="hidden" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="is_main_category[{{$row->id}}]" value=0>
                         <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="is_main_category[{{$row->id}}]" type="checkbox" value=1>  Main <i class="input-helper"></i>
                     </label>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: which bit doesn't work? the retrieval of data from request?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys my fault.

```
$segment_categories=DB::table('segment_categories')->create($segment_category_data;
```

should be

```
$segment_categories=DB::table('segment_categories')->insert($segment_category_data);
```